# Bound on local packing density of 2D Delaunay cell

Tags: ho.history-overview, sphere-packing

What is the history of the result that in a packing of the plane by unit disks, no Delaunay cell can be occupied by disk-sectors whose total measure exceeds $\pi/\sqrt{12}$ times the area of the cell?

I saw this in a two-page article that gave a nice simple proof, but (a) I can no longer locate the article, and (b) it was unclear to me when I read it whether the two authors (Taiwanese mathematicians, I think) were claiming that they were the first to prove the claim, or that their proof was significantly different from earlier proofs.

Comment: I think Axel Thue proved this in order to establish that the hexagonal lattice is the optimal packing of unit discs in the plane.

Comment: Thue's proof is described in some later literature as having been incomplete; I've read that Laszlo Fejes-Toth gave the first rigorous, complete solution to the sphere packing problem in two dimensions.

Comment: I think you will find the reference in: 
Rogers, C. A., Packing and covering, Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics and Mathematical Physics, No. 54 Cambridge University Press, New York 1964. (MR0172183).
The so-called "simplex bound" is proved there for every dimension $n\ge2$, but it is sharp in dimension $2$ only.

Comment: Also, it is known that in dimension $2$, for any packing with congruent circles, no Voronoi region is of area smaller than the area of the regular hexagon circumscribed about the circle. This was proved by György Hajós, if I remember correctly, but I do not have a reference to that.

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher: This is not the way Axel Thue established the maximum density of a circle packing. Although Thue's first "proof" (1890) was incorrect, he redeemed himself with another proof in 1910.

Comment: "I saw this in a two-page article that gave a nice simple proof, but..." – I think you mean this article, Jim:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.4322 .

Comment: Yes, Wlodek, that was the very article I was thinking of. Thanks! But I am still left wondering who first proved the simplex bound in two dimensions. (It's not hard to do, but someone must have been the first to do it.) My library has Böröczky's "Finite packing and covering" in its stacks but not the Rogers book.